# how to get 'python -i' to read PYTHONSTARTUP file?

Tags: python

I'm running Python 3.7.5.

When I'm developing a program `myprog.py`, I frequently run

```
$ python3 -i myprog.py
```

This lets me test functions interactively, which is super useful.

Unfortunately, as described in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#miscellaneous-options), `python3 -i` does not read the file pointed to by the PYTHONSTARTUP environment variable, :

> -i
>
> When a script is passed as first argument or the -c option is used, enter   interactive mode after executing the script or the command, even when sys.stdin does not appear to be a terminal. **The PYTHONSTARTUP file is not read**.

This means that all of my favorite imports and helper functions that I've defined in my PYTHONSTARTUP file are unavailable.

Is there some practical way around this?  The best workaround I've found is to run

```
$ python3
>>> from myprog import *
>>>
```

instead of `python3 -i myprog.py`.  However this involves more typing every time I modify `myprog.py` and restart the Python session.  Is there a better way?

Comment: it is strange that it doesn't load file from `PYTHONSTARTUP` because when you run `python --help` it shows `PYTHONSTARTUP: file executed on interactive startup (no default)`. Maybe first check if this variable is set before you run code. Check also if is correct full path. OR maybe it loads it after running `myprog` when it starts interactive mode.

Comment: BTW: in file loaded from `PYTHONSTARTUP` you can add code which checks if there is `myprog.py` in current folder and import it automatically. Eventually you can use tools like AutoHotkey (Windows) or AutoKey (Linux) to create shortcut to put some code much faster.

Comment: The Python documentation explicitly states that the PYTHONSTARTUP file is not read if you specify `-i`.  I've just edited my question to make that more clear.  So this behavior is documented.  I'm trying to find some way around it.

Comment: I'd rather not add code to my PYTHONSTARTUP file that looks for a specific program such as `myprog.py`, since I work on lots of different programs and would have to change this code every time I switch programs.

Comment: `from myprog import *` doesn't work with any script that uses an `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard, and global variable scope doesn't work the way it does with `-i`, so it's not a very good workaround.

Comment: I agree that it's not a great workaround.  This seems like such a common use case that I'm surprised that there isn't obviously a better way.

Answer (score -1):

if you are using Windows just type

py myprog.py

python myprog.py

it will run easy and you can modify your code without restart

Don't Forget to put python into your path

like if you are using git path or cmd with atom just follow this

mkdir newfolderName
cd newfolderName
ls newfolderName
myprog.py  #should contain you Python_file

then type "atom ." if you have it with dot . or your IDE then type

py myprog.py
or
python myprog.py

you will get the result

Comment: If I run `python myprog.py`, Python will run my program and then exit, so I'll be back at the command prompt.  But instead, I want Python to run my program and then stay in the interactive interpreter - that's what the `-i` option does.